# Why is span appearing strangely?

Tags: html, css

So I have a span element that is near an image. The surrounding elements have no padding or margin that would block it. But for some reason, the image is messing it up. I can't change the image's CSS to `position: absolute;` as it ends up screwing the dimensions, and it messes up the responsiveness.

In the Stack Overflow version, it seems fine, but as soon as you scale it up, it looks odd.

```css
body{
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.pfp{
  width:4%;
  height:4%;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.name{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:.5%;
  margin-right:.2%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.user-tag{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:.2%;
  color:grey;
  padding:0;
}
.date{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0%;
  color:grey;
}
.text{
 display:block;
 margin-left:5%;
}
.tweet{
  margin:3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tweet">
      <img class="pfp" src="https://walli.quosmos.com/files/thumbs/4/3/4/4347c0a1e9e62b48b3692aa0ea5707165f6c0f15/TesselationV__800_800.png"></img>
      <span class="name">John Doe</span>
      <span class="user-tag">@JohnDoe</span>
      <span class="date">· Feb 25</span>
      <span class="text">The image is also scaled oddly.</span>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is it sent downwards, and is there anyway to fix it?
I know it's a `display:block;` element, but if I don't give it that, it will appear on the same line as the info.

Comment: You mean the second line of text is pushed down? Because it's a block element?

Comment: It is the behaviour given by display:block;, it has such css property because it has the text class

Comment: If I don't give it that, it's on the same line, because span elements are inline.

Comment: Yes, but if you make it a block it will be on a new line because that's the behaviour of `block` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the image (.pfp) height to 100%, so the width will be set automatically.
If you then also add a wrapper for the upper line and set the position to relative and its height to 2em it should have a nice height for one line of text and the image will never be to big.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.pfp {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.name {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: .5%;
  margin-right: .2%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.user-tag {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: .2%;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0;
}

.date {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0%;
  color: grey;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.tweet {
  margin: 3%;
}

.tweetheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tweet">
    <div class="tweetheader">
      <img class="pfp" src="https://walli.quosmos.com/files/thumbs/4/3/4/4347c0a1e9e62b48b3692aa0ea5707165f6c0f15/TesselationV__800_800.png"></img>
      <span class="name">John Doe</span>
      <span class="user-tag">@JohnDoe</span>
      <span class="date">· Feb 25</span> </div>
    <span class="text">The image is also scaled oddly.</span>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```css
body{
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.pfp{
  width:4%;
  height:4%;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.name{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:.5%;
  margin-right:.2%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.user-tag{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:.2%;
  color:grey;
  padding:0;
}
.date{
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0%;
  color:grey;
}
.text{
 display:block;
 margin-left:5%;
}
.tweet{
  margin:3%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tweet">
      <img class="pfp" src="https://walli.quosmos.com/files/thumbs/4/3/4/4347c0a1e9e62b48b3692aa0ea5707165f6c0f15/TesselationV__800_800.png"></img>
      <span class="name">John Doe</span>
      <span class="user-tag">@JohnDoe</span>
      <span class="date">· Feb 25</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">The image is also scaled oddly.</span>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```